# glxspheres not found. How to install?

Tags: kubuntu, beta

I installed kubuntu 13.10 beta 1 yesterday. Today, I installed bumblebee and I was tried to check my fps on video card. When I ran `glxspheres` an error *command not found* appeared. How can I install `glxspheres`?

I tried `sudo apt-get install virtualgl` but the package was not found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Download VirtualGL (.deb) from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/VirtualGL/
2. Navigate to the folder containing the deb package and install it with:

   `sudo dpkg -i VirtualGL_*.deb`
3. Run glxspheres:

   `cd /opt/VirtualGL/bin/`

   `./glxspheres`

   **OR**

   `/opt/VirtualGL/bin/glxspheres`

Comment: bash: /opt/VirtualGL/bin/glxspheres: File not found

Comment: My error :( i need run glxspheres64 thx for help :)

Comment: The website address should now be: http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/VirtualGL/ pick the newest stable version, and then choose the deb release.

Comment: Note: `glxspheres` seems to be `/usr/bin/glxspheres64` in the x86_64 `virtualgl` package nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

In 13.04 and older it is provided by `mesa-utils` package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Also in older releases `virtualgl` is not in the default repositories. If this is still the case you can use [Bumblebee PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable) to get it.

Comment: I have added this PPA but now bash sad virtualgl is the latest version and glxspheres not found :(

Comment: So, even after doing that `apt-get install` you still get that error with `glxspheres`?

Comment: @Salem he's using Ubuntu+1, or more accurately Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander, hence, normal methods could not work.

Comment: This is the most native and easiest one. Only sphere won't be there but glxgears can do the job or it's friends.