# No devices found when trying to use NVIDIA GPU

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, primus

I'm attempting to use Bumblebee for my NVIDIA GPU, and I'm running into errors when running programs.

I'm testing it with a Minecraft client, which actually starts, but crashes after a moment.

```
$ primusrun java -jar Minecraft.jar
# some normal output...
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.
```

I can see the card just fine:

```
$ lspci | grep 3D
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
```

This setup ran fine under Arch on this same machine. Not sure what isn't configured properly.

EDIT:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:0650]
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

My main graphics card is Intel, since this is an optimus machine.

EDIT 2:

```
$ optirun -vv --debug glxspheres
[ 2643.983966] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 2643.984989] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[ 2643.985038] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 2643.985066] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 2643.985096] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 2643.985123] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-304:/usr/lib32/nvidia-304
[ 2643.985152] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 2643.985179] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[ 2643.985207] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[ 2643.985235] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[ 2643.985262] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[ 2643.985525] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[ 2644.041849] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.

[ 2644.041877] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.

[ 2644.041890] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 2644.041912] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[ 2644.041923] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

EDIT 3:

My `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"

#   If the X server does not automatically detect your VGA device,
#   you can manually set it here.
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
#   as you see in the commented example.
#   This Setting may be needed in some platforms with more than one
#   nvidia card, which may confuse the proprietary driver (e.g.,
#   trying to take ownership of the wrong device). Also needed on Ubuntu 13.04.
    BusID "PCI:01:00.0"

#   Setting ProbeAllGpus to false prevents the new proprietary driver
#   instance spawned to try to control the integrated graphics card,
#   which is already being managed outside bumblebee.
#   This option doesn't hurt and it is required on platforms running
#   more than one nvidia graphics card with the proprietary driver.
#   (E.g. Macbook Pro pre-2010 with nVidia 9400M + 9600M GT).
#   If this option is not set, the new Xorg may blacken the screen and
#   render it unusable (unless you have some way to run killall Xorg).
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"

    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```

Comment: what do you get when you run: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

Comment: Can you post the results of `optirun -vv --debug glxspheres` for us? If you see `[ERROR]Error running "glxspheres": NO such file or directory"` try the solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/344216/glxspheres-not-found-how-to-install) and then retry it

Comment: you're not using `nvidia` driver as you can see but `i915` read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) and [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) article to get more details.

Comment: I had already changed the `conf` file before submitting this question, and it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: did you insert/paste your GPU BusID to `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`?

Comment: I just said that I did. Config file above...

Answer (score 6):

```
[ERROR] Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.
```

You need to edit the `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` (or `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau` if using the noveau driver) and specify the correct BusID by following the instructions therein.

your `xorg.conf` should look like this for example:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce XXXXX"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection
```

find out and replace `XXXX` with your exact `BoardName` and `BusID` with command:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info
```

After this restart `sudo service lightdm restart` or reboot will work.

Comment: `nvidia-xconfig` isn't found. Whatever package contains it isn't mentioned on the Bumblebee wiki page.

Comment: run: `optirun nvidia-settings` it's listed in `nvidia-settings` as well

Comment: I cannot run anything under `optirun` or `primusrun`. That is what this whole issue is about. By extension, `optirun nvidia-settings` isn't going to happen. Also, running it normally doesn't show any GPU-related info.

Comment: The BusID was in `lspci` as far as I could tell. Otherwise, I suppose it is incorrect. My problem is figuring out the exact `BoardName` it is looking for.

Comment: it should be `GeForce GT 750M` or as stated [here](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2224/geforce-gt-750m.html)

Comment: This doesn't appear to have changed anything. I'm still getting the same output.

Comment: I'm not thick; I followed the instructions. All you did was copy the wiki page which I already read...

Comment: BusID was mentioned, if you look under the first comment block. Adding BoardName had no effect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if comment lines affected functionality, they would not be in the default config as such. The line itself is not commented out, only some above it, and the line exists before `EndSection`.

Comment: check this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/289659/using-nvidia-319-with-bumblebee

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` , uncomment

```
BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
```

and replace it with

```
BusID "PCI:0x:00.0"
```

where x is the number that you see in `lspci` list next to "3D controller", which should be your nvidia card

Comment: Good answer!  ;-)  Please review my edits by clicking on the "edited" link above my avatar and review the http://askubuntu.com/editing-help as well!  :P  ;-)